# How to make componentWillMount to await until token is stored in local storage

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I am trying to store jwt token in local storage on app startup but the render method gets called even before the token is stored in local storage. Could you please help to componentWillMount to wait until token is stored in local storage?

Index.js

```
 componentWillMount() {        
            AuthRepository.getToekn();
        }
```

AuthRepository.js

```
class AuthRepository {
    constructor(callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }
       
    async getToekn() {   
        const reponse = await axios
            .post(`${baseUrl}/auth/local`, {                
                identifier:(process.env.IDENTIFIER).trim(),
                password:(process.env.IDENTIFIER_PWD).trim(),
            })
            .then((response) => {                   
                setTrapiToken(response.data.jwt)            
                return response.data.jwt;
            })
            .catch((error) => ({ error: JSON.stringify(error) }));
        return reponse;
    }
}
export default new AuthRepository();
```

Function to set token

```
export const setTrapiToken = (token) => {
    console.log('here')
    console.log(token)
    try{
      localStorage.setItem(process.env.JWT_KEY,token); 
      return true;     
    }catch(e){
        console.log('false')
      return false;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Don't you just have to `await` for your `AuthRepository.getToekn();` to resolve? Afterwards you're guaranteed that the item is in `localStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

React's rendering never waits - and so mounting also never waits.
If you like it or not, that component is mounted. So all you can do is check if the data is already in place and display some kind of loading indicator if it isn't yet.